# Upload large file (>2GB) with multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload a large file (7GB) to my server. For this I'm using `multer`:

```
const express = require('express');

const multer = require('multer');

const {
    saveLogFile,
} = require('../controller/log');

const router = express.Router();
const upload = multer();

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), saveLogFile);
```

In my `saveLogFile` controller, which is of format `saveLogFile = async (req,res) => { ... }` I want to get `req.file`. The `multer` package should give me the uploaded file with `req.file`. So when I try to upload small files (<2GB) It goes successfully. But when I try to upload files over 2GB, I get the following error:

```
buffer.js:364
    throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE.RangeError('size', size);
    ^

RangeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "7229116782" is invalid for option "size"
```

How can I bypass it? Actually, All I need is access for the uploaded file in my `saveLogFile` Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is probably that node will run out of memory as your using multer without passing any options. From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multeropts):

> In case you omit the options object, the files will be kept in memory
> and never written to disk.

Try using the `dest` or `storage` option in order to use a temporary file for the upload:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: './some-upload-folder' });
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), saveLogFile);
```